# is there some way to change the header with other in only one page?

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress site and I'm working on the page builder but idk how to change the header in the home page, I have like 10 different pages including the home. And 2 different headers... I remember that you had to put in the CSS customizer the CSS values like this:

```
.page-id-32 header{
display: none;
}
```

But before the header part I remember that you could specify the page header that you want to omit and in other put the one that you want to be displayed in the said section... is there a way that I could disappear one header and put other in only one page of my site? I'm working with free pagelayer and free popularfx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. There're some ways.
First one you'll need to go into the php WP code and try something like this: https://www.webascender.com/blog/how-to-create-multiple-headers-footers-in-wordpress/

You can try doing it via JS script adding show/hide classes depending on the page you want header variations. For this approach you will need to get a selector for the page you want to change. So, that will be the hard part.

I think PHP approach is better, but that will require to get into the code. You'll have to download a WP file visualizer plugin.

Comment: any wp file visualizer plugin that you recomend?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-manager/

Comment: You can always download your code via FTP connecting to your hosting. Also, you can try with your hosting tool, like CPanel.